# Dashlet edit button in titlebar not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, alfresco, freemarker

I am trying to create a simple Alfresco dashlet with an edit button enabled on the title bar. Unfortunately, I can not figure out how to get the edit button to actually *display* on the title bar.

Here is what I have so far:

**dashlet desc file** (.desc.xml)

```
<webscript>
   <shortname>Sample</shortname>
   <description>Displays a Sample dashlet</description>
   <family>dashlet</family>
   <url>/mycompany/components/dashlets/sample-dashlet</url>
</webscript>
```

**My main freemarker template file** (.ftl)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var sampleDashlet = new MyCompany.dashlet.SampleDashlet("${args.htmlid}").setOptions({
        "componentId": "${instance.object.id}",
        "siteId": "${page.url.templateArgs.site!""}",
        "title": "${msg("header")}"
    }).setMessages(${messages});
    new Alfresco.widget.DashletResizer("${args.htmlid}", "${instance.object.id}");

    var editDashletEvent = new YAHOO.util.CustomEvent("onDashletConfigure");
    editDashletEvent.subscribe(sampleDashlet.onConfigClick, sampleDashlet, true);

    new Alfresco.widget.DashletTitleBarActions("${args.htmlid}").setOptions({
        actions: [{
            cssClass: "edit",
            eventOnClick: editDashletEvent,
            tooltip: "${msg("dashlet.edit.tooltip")?js_string}"
        }]
    });
    //]]>
</script>

<div class="dashlet-1"> 
 <div> Test </div>
</div>
```

It seems as if the problem must be in my configuration somewhere, but I can't find it. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: You have not included the implementation of the MyCompany.dashlet.SampleDashlet client side JavaScript component. That should reside in a JavaScript file that is referenced in head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a working example of a very simple dashlet that is set up to be configurable in this way, see http://code.google.com/p/alfresco-get-latest-document. This blog post sets up the basic functionality: http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/05/08/1592. And this blog post expands on that to make the initial dashlet configurable: http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/05/15/1599.

In comparing your FTL with mine, I'm wondering if your div classes/id need to follow this pattern:

```
  <div class="dashlet getlatestdoc">
  <div id="getlatestdoc_title" class="title">
    ${title}
  </div>
```

Otherwise, how will the edit button know where to render itself?

Answer (score 1):

As Jeff suggests, you need to include a `<div>` element for the dashlet's title bar in your markup with an appropriate value for the `class` attribute, as follows

```
<div class="dashlet dashlet-1">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="body">Body content</div>
</div>
```

When the `Alfresco.widget.DashletTitleBarActions` instance that your inline JavaScript code creates gets instantiated it will look for a child `<div>` with the class `title` and will add the actions there.

I also added a `dashlet` class to the parent div, which is required for the default dashlet styles to be applied.